# How do I add swipe back gesture in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I found a question like this on Stack Overflow however it did not seem to work. Maybe I'm implementing it wrong, or it no longer works. I have a @Binding showDetailView that when equals true, shows the detail view.

This detail view has a custom back button that works. I want to be able to do a swipe gesture that performs the same function as the back button.

The code I found that looks like it could help is:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

The code for my main view (product page) is:

```
struct ProductPage: View {
   
    
    @StateObject var MarketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    @State private var selectedMarketplaceFilter: MarketplaceFilterViewModel = .productList
    @Namespace var animation : Namespace.ID
    @State var showDetailProduct = false
    @State var selectedProduct : Product!
    
    var body: some View {
        

        var columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 2)
        
        ZStack{
            
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                
                
                if MarketplaceModel.products.isEmpty{
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    ProgressView()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                else{
                    
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                        

                        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 10), count: 2),spacing: 20){
                            
                            ForEach(MarketplaceModel.filteredProduct){product in
                                
                                    ProductView(productData: product)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            withAnimation {
                                                
                                                selectedProduct = product
                                                showDetailProduct.toggle()

                                            }
                                        }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            
           
            if selectedProduct != nil && showDetailProduct{

                ProductDetailView(showDetailProduct: $showDetailProduct, productData: selectedProduct, product_id)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
       }
    }
}
```

The code for my detail view (product detail view) is:

```
struct ProductDetailView: View {
    

    @StateObject var MarketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    @Binding var showDetailProduct: Bool
    @Namespace var animation: Namespace.ID
    @EnvironmentObject var marketplaceData: MarketplaceViewModel
    var productData : Product
    var product_id: String
    

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
        
        VStack{
            
            VStack{
                
                // Title Bar...
                HStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                                            withAnimation{showDetailProduct.toggle()}

                                        }) {
                                            Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle.fill")
                                            

                    Spacer()
                   
                    ForEach(MarketplaceModel.product_details_array){ items in

                        Text(items.product_name)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
            }
                
      ScrollView {


                VStack {
     
                    Text(productData.product_name)
                  
                    Text(productData.product_details)
                    
                }
            }
        
            
            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about adding the back swipe gesture? (Running Xcode 13.4.1)

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using navigation link ? (Which does the work)

Comment: The product page view is in a custom layout with each product being in a 'tile' type format. I was told that due to this I shouldn't use navigation link. Is Navigation Link something I should implement?

Comment: I think you were told this because the detail view contains a navigation view. The problem is that you are displaying a navigation view that handles gesture so as detail view is root it can not go  back.

Comment: I see, so if I removed NavigationView from the detail view, gestures can work?

Comment: I think it may work when declaring the swipe on the  detail view in the ZStack as you have scrollView in your details view. The most important is to find the place where there could be no conflict between gestures.